# Google Maps and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-maps

I have a Google App Engine application that launches a Web Page with Google Map.
I would now like to add functionality to let user sketch on map (which I can probably use JS API for) and then create a fusion table row using python code backend.
Is this possible?
If so how do I transfer the sketch coords from Javascript to Python backend?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is more of a Google Maps API question than an app engine question. You may want to retag it to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple guideline:

- Javascript and [overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#OverlaysOverview) to draw stuff on the maps
- [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to post json sketch data from the client to Google App Engine
- A well shaped rest interface on the server using [appengine-rest-server](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/)
- [Fusion-Tables python library](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/) to access Google Fusion Tables from GAE